# Using random forest in MATLAB

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, random-forest

I am having issues in using random forests in MATLAB. I have features of size 2000 and around 4000 data points. I am trying to learn how to compute random forests in MATLAB using the library [Random Forest](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31036-random-forest).

However, I guess it's too slow to use this method. I have set the number of trees to 500 and `mtry` to 720 and it is taking ages. Is it natural to take this long? How long does it normally take?

Comment: The implementation at:
http://code.google.com/p/randomforest-matlab/
is really a cool and fast one with a C implementation and MATLAB simple interface. 

Did you try also, the MATLAB's own implementation:

ens = TreeBagger(ntrees,X,Y)
[labels,score] = predict(ens,X)

Answer (score 1):

One more simple and easy thing that you can do is to use jar file provided by Weka(Data Mining Tool), and add that to the matlab path and use the classifier that you want to work with. This will allow you to access all the classifiers and filters in MATLAB using some simple functions, parameter tuning is also very easy.